# How can i download body canvas image?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html2canvas

```
html2canvas(document.body).then(function(canvas) {
            document.body.appendChild(canvas);
        });
```

I get screen shot using this method how can i download that image. i didn't wont to assign src tag for this.. i simply need download this image.

Comment: man i'm new to this. that answer is not what i need..

Comment: It's good to visit the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) when being new.

Answer (score 1):

```
            html2canvas(document.body, {
                onrendered: function(canvas) {
                    document.body.appendChild(canvas);
                    var dataURL=canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
                    $.ajax({
                      type: "POST",
                      url: "upload.php",
                      data: {image: dataURL}
                    }).done(function( respond ) {
                        window.opener.location.href ='http://Your_url/download.php?file_name='+respond+' ';
                     });
                }
```

You have to upload image and then after Download the image using php code